# How to get id(of a record) from a link when clicking on?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the id from the `href` link when clicking on `modal-view` class(in this case I want to return 6), but don't know how to do.

I tried `$this.attr('href')`(to check `attr` function is working or not) but it returned `undefined`.

Any suggestion, thanks in advance.

```
<span class="action_item modal-view">
  <a href="/admin/sponsoreds/6/edit">Edit Sponsored</a>
</span>
```

Comment: `$this` is the way to go indeed. It should've worked if used properly. The `$` makes me think jquery was involved as well. It could be due to a handful of reasons so could you maybe share the entire code that leads to this behavior?

Comment: How that link is generated? Why not just add extra `data-*` to the span iteself with those required info?

Comment: @Arvind it was generated automatically by active admin(rails).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code must be `$(this).find('a')`. `$(this)` is the object of clicked element and `find('a')` will search `a` tag inside the clicked element. And to get the id you can do something like `$(this).find('a').attr('href').split('/')[3]`. Here split will separate your value of `href` and make an array and can access it via its index.

```js
$('.modal-view').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
  console.log($(this).find('a').attr('href').split('/')[3])
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="action_item modal-view">
  <a href="/admin/sponsoreds/6/edit">Edit Sponsored</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you use jQuery:

```
$("span.action_item.modal-view").click(function(){
    let href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    console.log(href);
});
```

`.prop()` should work also

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom attribute like `itemId` to `<a>` tag then retrieve it as you need.

Answer (score 0):

By jQuery we can do it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
       alert("id of the link ="+this.id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see there is no `id` associated with the HTML piece of code you have attached. You need to associate it with `id` inorder to access it from the DOM.

```
<span class="action_item modal-view">
  <a id="anc-id" href="/admin/sponsoreds/6/edit">Edit Sponsored</a>
</span>
```

From your above description, i sense you are using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a").attr("id"); //anc-id
});
```

If there are many `a` tags in your page, for more specific way to filter out by using class -

```
<span id="parent-id" class="action_item modal-view">
  <a class="anc" id="anc-id" href="/admin/sponsoreds/6/edit">Edit Sponsored</a>
</span>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a.anc").attr("id");
});
```

If there are many `a` tags with class `.anc` then we need to loop the `a` inorder to fetch all the ids.

Solution 2 -

If your need is just to grab the element without having any `id` then -

```
var element = $("span.modal-view > a");

element.addClass("newClass");
element.append('...');
```

Check this for more information - https://api.jquery.com/element-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex on the `href` to find the ID. I've assumed it is always a number in the answer below.

```js
function onTriggerClicked(event) {
  // Cancel the navigation to the href or the example will fail.
  event.preventDefault();
  
  const
    // Get the href attribute from the clicked element.
    href = event.target.href,
    // Create regex which will match "/" + (one or more digits) + "/".
    regex = /\/(\d+)\//,
    // Perform the regex on the href.
    match = regex.exec(href);
  
  // When match is null it means the href doesn't contain one or more 
  // digits sandwiched "/"
  if (match === null) {
    console.log('no valid ID found in href');
  } else {
    // The regex found a number, it is in the first capture group
    // so it can find in item 1 of the match array.
    console.log('The ID in the href is: ', regex.exec(href)[1]);
  }
}

// Add a click listener to each of the elements with the modal-view class.
const
  triggers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.modal-view'));
triggers.forEach(trigger => trigger.addEventListener('click', onTriggerClicked));
```

```html
<span class="action_item modal-view">
  <a href="/admin/sponsoreds/6/edit">Edit Sponsored</a>
</span>
<span class="action_item modal-view">
  <a href="/admin/sponsoreds/61/edit">Edit Sponsored 2</a>
</span>
<span class="action_item modal-view">
  <a href="/admin/sponsoreds/6a/edit">Edit Sponsored 3</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can get value of `href` by using `$(this).find('a').attr('href')`, then you need to split returned uri to get this numeric value (id) like,

```
$(".modal-view").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).find('a').attr('href').split('/')[3];
    console.log(id) // 6
})
```

Now `id` contains value required.